# C++ Compiler error C2440

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error but I don't understand what is wrong:

> Error 7   error C2440: 'initializing' :
>   cannot convert from
>   'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> *' to
>   'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> *'
>   c:\documents
>   and settings\vay\my documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\projects\socks\chatserver\server.h   107

This is the relevant code:

```
std::pair<std::string, ChatClient&> *p
     = new std::pair<std::string, ChatClient>(username, *sock );
```

Comment: This is the line : std::pair<std::string, ChatClient&> *p = new std::pair<std::string, ChatClient>(username, *sock );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two pairs are different.

Remove the `&`:

```
std::pair<std::string, ChatClient> *p = new std::pair<std::string, ChatClient>(...);
```

Comment: std::pair<std::string, ChatClient&> *p = new std::pair<std::string, ChatClient>(username, *sock );

Comment: @Vijay: yes, and as Erik indicated, this line is wrong, on the left you write `ChatClient&` and on the right `ChatClient`, those are different types.